# Язык C, аргументы функций типа "массив"

Tags: c, массивы

Рассмотрим несколько объявлений функций:

```
void f_1(int *_arr);
void f_2(int _arr[]);
void f_3(int _arr[100])

void f_4(int **_arr);
void f_5(int _arr[][]);
void f_6(int _arr[100][100]);
```

Верно ли я понимаю, что:

1) В списке аргументов функций и только в нем записи вида **int *_arr** и **int _arr[]** синонимичны?

2) Для чего существует возможность задавать размер массива в аргументах функции? Не припоминаю, чтобы где-то это использовалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) В списке аргументов функций и только в нем записи вида `int *_arr` и `int _arr[]` синонимичны?

Да, все так.

Но обратите внимание, что у многомерных массивов в звездочку превращается только самый левый индекс. То есть `int _arr[50][100]` становится `int (*_arr)[100]`.

(Это не какое-то особое правило для многомерных массивов, а следствие того, что формально они являются одномерными массивами одномерных массивов. Обрабатываются они точно так же, как и обычные одномерные массивы.)

А вот запись вида `int _arr[][]` - невалидна.
(Мой GCC выдает `error: array type has incomplete element type 'int[]'`.)
Можно написать `int (*_arr)[]`, но такая запись не имеет большого смысла.

---

> Для чего существует возможность задавать размер массива в аргументах функции?

Если размер константный, то его можно ставить просто для удобства чтения программы.

Answer (score 2):

1. Да, все так. Это, разумеется, относится только к первому размеру массива, т.е. к `f_1`, `f_2` и `f_3`, но не к `f_4`, `f_5` и `f_6`. Для последних это правило даст следующий набор синонимичных определений

   ```
   void f_4(int (*_arr)[100]);
   void f_6(int _arr[][100]);
   ```

   Объявление `f_5` просто некорректно, хотя стоит обратить внимание на то, что 
   эквивалентное определение

   ```
   void f_5(int (*_arr)[])
   ```

   вполне легально (но не эквивалентно `f_4` и `f_5`).
2. Изначально размер массива поддерживался в этом контексте чисто ради единообразия с объявлениями массивов в других контекстах. Однако начиная с C99 появился вариант

   ```
   void foo(int arr[static 100])
   ```

   который по-прежнему объявляет параметр типа `int *` (и не заставляет компилятор выполнять никакой диагностики), но даем вам возможность "пообещать" компилятору, что вы будете предавать массивы-аргументы размера не менее `100`. Это может позволить компилятору лучше оптимизировать код.